# How to implement content assist's documentation popup in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, code-completion, eclipse-pde

I have implemented my own editor and added a code completion functionality to it. My content assistant is registered in source viewer configuration like this:

```java
public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    if (assistant == null) {
        assistant = new ContentAssistant();
        assistant.setDocumentPartitioning(getConfiguredDocumentPartitioning(sourceViewer));
        assistant.setContentAssistProcessor(getMyAssistProcessor(),
                MyPartitionScanner.DESIRED_PARTITION_FOR_MY_ASSISTANCE);
        assistant.enableAutoActivation(true);
        assistant.setAutoActivationDelay(500);
        assistant.setProposalPopupOrientation(IContentAssistant.PROPOSAL_OVERLAY);
        assistant.setContextInformationPopupOrientation(IContentAssistant.CONTEXT_INFO_ABOVE);
    }
    return assistant;
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> inside the desired partition, the completion popup appears and works as expected.

And here's my question.. How do I implement/register a documentation popup that appears next to completion popup? (For example in java editor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

I'll answear the question myself ;-)

You have to add this line

```
assistant.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));
```

to the configuration above. Then when creating **CompletionProposals**, the eighth (last) parameter called **additionalProposalInfo** of the constructor is the text, which will be shown in the documentation popup.

```
new CompletionProposal(replacementString,
                          replacementOffset,
                          replacementLength,
                          cursorPosition,
                          image,
                          displayString,
                          contextInformation,
                          additionalProposalInfo);
```

More information about can be found [here](http://www.50001.com/language/javaside/lec/java_ibm/Equipping%20SWT%20%BE%D6%C7%C3%B8%AE%C4%C9%C0%CC%BC%C7%BF%A1%20content%20assistants%20%C3%DF%B0%A1%C7%CF%B1%E2%20(%BF%B5%B9%AE).htm).

Easy, isn't it.. if you know how to do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

For the styled information box (just like in JDT).

[image: Styled additionnal information]

---

The [DefaultInformationControl](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/DefaultInformationControl.html) instance need to received a `HTMLTextPresenter`.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.html.HTMLTextPresenter;

public class MyConfiguration extends SourceViewerConfiguration {


    [...]
    public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        if (assistant == null) {
            [...]
            assistant.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));
        }
        return assistant;
    }

    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getInformationControlCreator(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        return new IInformationControlCreator() {
            public IInformationControl createInformationControl(Shell parent) {
                return new DefaultInformationControl(parent,new HTMLTextPresenter(false));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Proposals can then use basic HTML tags in the string from method [getAdditionalProposalInfo()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/contentassist/ICompletionProposal.html).

```
public class MyProposal implements ICompletionProposal {
    [...]
    @Override
    public String getAdditionalProposalInfo() {
        return "<b>Hello</b> <i>World</i>!";
    }
}
```