# Eclipse Rcp - How to get custom PopUp Menu in text editor on ctrl + space on text

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

We have seen that in eclipse Java Editor, when we perform (ctrl + space) key on the objectname, a popup menu appears showing list of methods and variables of that class.

In my case, it is not a java editor. But I want to achieve similar functionality as mentioned above.

I have 30 fix objects, when that object appears in the text editor and I do (ctrl + space) key at the end of object name, I need to show popup menu with its member variables.

Could you please guide me how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a JFace content assistant in your SourceViewerConfiguration, compare this question: [How to implement content assist's documentation popup in Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887248/how-to-implement-content-assists-documentation-popup-in-eclipse-rcp)

This page got even more examples: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContentAssistant

And this is the official Eclipse FAQ for this feature: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_Content_Assist_to_my_editor%3F

Comment: Thanks All for your help. IContentAssistant would help me achieve my target.

Answer (score -1):

Use `KeyStroke controlspace = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);`

Do somthing like this example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class KeyTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    KeyTest frame = new KeyTest();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public KeyTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JLabel lblClickHereAnd = new JLabel("Click here and press Ctrl+Space");
        contentPane.add(lblClickHereAnd, BorderLayout.NORTH);

         InputMap inputMap = contentPane.getInputMap();
         inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "foo");
         contentPane.getActionMap().put("foo", new AbstractAction() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 System.out.println("Key pressed");
             }
         });
         pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: A shame this didn't work for Eclipse (it uses SWT). I needed this for a Swing project and it worked!